# UIWebView in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview

i am not sure if this is a good route to go,...i have some data i receive from the web which in turn, populates a table view. The problem is, the text is html (p tags, etc). My first thought was to create a uiwebview in the cell, and populate with loadHTMLString. Fact is , it KINDA works. But, i then the cell no longer was the recipient of touches.

SO, before we get too deep in code, is there a better way to populate the cells, than using a UIWebView. It feels like a hack, and i fear even if it works, apple would turn it away.

//from my custom UITableViewCell class:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
    [self setFrame:frame];

    webcell = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,frame.size.width-20,frame.size.height)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:webcell];

    //bloack the webview from touches
    UIView *cover = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:webcell.frame];
    [self.contentView addSubview:cover];
    [cover release];
}
return self;
```

}

-(void)setLabelData:(FeedItem *)feedItem
{
    link = feedItem.link;

```
NSMutableString *htmlstring = [NSMutableString string];
[htmlstring appendString:@"<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/></head><body>"];
[htmlstring appendFormat:@"<p>%@</p>",feedItem.title];
[htmlstring appendFormat:@"<p>%@</p>",feedItem.description];
[htmlstring appendString:@"</body></html>"];
[webcell loadHTMLString:htmlstring baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath]]];
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless someone out there has rebuttle, i have concluded that a UIWebView in a UITableViewCell is not a good idea. Albeit, i have not tested with a local htmlString...

Answer (score 0):

We've had some success using webviews in cells.  If you want the cell to receive touch events, you need to set the webview's `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO.  You also need to use a different reuseIdentifier for each cell, since the webview takes some time to load its contents and may get reused before it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by statically allocating the webview-cells as soon as I know how many I will need for the table, and start them all loading off-screen.  No reuse identifiers, you need to keep track of the cells and where they go yourself.